# Why can a signal handler not run during system calls?

Tags: linux, signals

In Linux a process that is waiting for IO can be in either of the states `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` or `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE`.

The latter, for example, is the case when the process waits until the `read` from a regular file completes. If this `read` takes very long or forever (for whatever reasons), it leads to the problem that the process cannot receive any signals during that time.

The former, is the case if, for example, one waits for a `read` from a socket (which may take an unbounded amount of time). If such a `read` call gets interrupted, however, it leads to the problem that it requires the programmer/user to handle the `errno == EINTER` condition correctly, which he might forget.

My question is: Wouldn't it be possible to allow all system calls to be interrupted by signals and, moreover, in such a way that after the signal handler ran, the original system call simply continues its business? Wouldn't this solve both problems? If it is not possible, why?

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer would involve going deeper into CPU and OS internals than I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two halves of the question are related but I may have digested too much spiked eggnog to determine if there is so much a one-to-one as opposed to a one-to-several relationship here.

On the kernel side I think a `TASK_KILLABLE` state was added a couple of years back.  The consequence of that was that while the process blocked in a system call (for whatever reason), if the kernel encountered a  signal that was going to kill the process anyway, it would let nature take its course.  That reduces the chances of a process being permanent stuck in an uninterruptible state.  What progress has been made in changing individual system calls to avail themselves of that option I do not know.

On the user side, `SA_RESTART` and its convenience function cousin `siginterrupt` go some distance to alleviating the application programmer pain.  But the fact that these are specified per signal and aren't honored by all system calls is a pretty good hint that there are reasons why a blanket interruption scheme like you propose can't be implemented, or at least easily implemented.  Just thinking about the possible interactions of the matrices of signals, individual system calls, calls that have historically expected and backwardly supported behavior (and possibly multiple historical semantics based on their system bloodline!), is a bit dizzying.  But maybe that is the eggnog.